# multi-staged form using spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring

please forgive me for this stupid questions. I just started developing web application using spring yesterday.

The project that i worked on, have a multi staged form, that require users to complete them before the data can be persisted on the database. Is there any way to keep those input in a temporary storage eg: session scoped bean, before the user finish all the stages? or any suggestion what is the best way to implement this using spring mvc?

thanks a lot, please pardon my grammar

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Spring webflow.](http://www.springsource.org/webflow)  It is a module on top of Spring's MVC that is designed to support multi-step workflows.